# jquery mobile - touchstart does not work on Chrome & Safari IOS?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

jquery mobile `touchstart` does not seem to work on Chrome & Safari on IOS:

```
$(document).on("click touchstart", "a[href^='#']", function (e) {
  var id = $(this).attr("href");
  if ($(id).length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // trigger scroll
    scrollMagicController.scrollTo(id);

      // if supported by the browser we can even update the URL.
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
      history.pushState("", document.title, id);
    }
  }
});
```

It works fine on Chrome 5.5, 5.8 Android. But not on Chrome 5.7 IOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `$(document).on("vclick", "a[href='#']", function(e) {`, BTW remove the `^`...

Comment: @deblocker thanks for the help. what does `^` do btw?

Comment: don't know if it is just only in the question or also in the code `"a[href^='#']"`

Comment: `^=` means starts with